# HTML data into JavaScript function issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that uses a weather plugin (https://a12k.io/reallysimpleweather), my problem is that I am wondering how to use the data that is gathered from a user via the HTML form element like below,

```
<script>var input = document.getElementById('cityInput').value;</script>

<script>
reallySimpleWeather.weather({
  //var city = "Bend, Or";
  wunderkey: '', // leave blank for Yahoo API
    location: input,
    woeid: '', // "Where on Earth ID" optional alternative to location
    unit: 'f', // 'c' also works
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2>'+weather.temp+'°'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';
    document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = html;
    },
    error: function(error) {
    document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = '<p>'+error+'</p>';
    }
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="weather"></div>

<form>
City: <input type="text" name="city" id="cityInput">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm unsure as to if my issue is caused because of how the page and the API I am calling might be loading, but when I open it all up in a browser I am currently just getting an error from the plugin that says "There is a problem receiving the latest weather. Try again." Im not sure if this is caused because it is not able to update itself once it is initially loaded or if its because I am incorrectly storing the variable wrong in

```
 location: input,
```

Whenever I hit "submit" nothing changes expect the URL itself changes to add `city=%27Bend%2C+OR%27`
at the end or whatever the city entered is.

Comment: well you need to call it after the user enters the data....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value using JavaScript and put where you want:

```
<form action="begin-create-done.html" method="get">
    City: <input type="text" name="city" id="cityInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In JavaScript:

```
var value = document.getElementByName( "city" ).value;
// or
// var value = document.getElementById( "cityInput" ).value;

reallySimpleWeather.weather({
    wunderkey: '',
    location: value,
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
        html =  '<h2>'+weather.temp+'°'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
        html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
        html += '<li>'+weather.currently+'</li>';
        html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';
        document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = html;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = '<p>'+error+'</p>';
    }
});
```

Please, note that you will need to use the "id" attribute of the input tag to be able to catch this input through JavaScript. Not that inside your code will already used the document.getElementById() function. You will need an div to insert the html generated by the success function and this div must have the id attribute set to "weather".

Also, note that `reallySimpleWeather.weather` is a function that receives an object with various attributes. You can't set an variable inside this object. It is a syntax error. You must declare it before the `reallySimpleWeather.weather` call. Take a look above.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. This might be a "read the docs" type situation, but I have tried a few variations of that without luck. For example I have tried declaring the variable value, like you mentioned right at the start of the reallySimpleWeather.weather function above like,  var value = document.getElementByName( "city" ).value; However this then removed the data altogether being displayed?

Comment: Its because you tried to declare a variable in a not allowed region. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I also added in an edit to original to maybe give a little more clarification.

Comment: @jelidens take a look.

Comment: thanks again for the help, I've tried what you have suggested and it does seem to make more sense, but I'm still not getting the page to actually refresh itself with the new value. I have changed a lot above which might help give a better understanding

Comment: Do you want to keep calliing the reallySimpleWeather.weather function within a time interval?

Comment: maybe? But really what i am wanting is for a user to be able to type in the parameters that the weather function requires for the city name. So like Bend, Or or WhateverTown, NY and then it shows that citys data like it does when I have it hard set on a city like  " location: Bend, Or,"

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the input an ID (e.g. `<input type="text" name="city" id="city">`)to make it easy to select say with:

```
var city = document.getElementById('city');
```

Then change the line in your plugin call to reference the value:

```
location: city.value,
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am currently working with this suggestion and others.

Answer (score 1):

Give your input city an id and than you use getElementById to put that city in place for your location variable

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am currently reading into this and others.